# my website can get ping but status always "Waiting" when visiting via browser

Tags: ping, website, timeout, time-wait

When i tried to use CMD.exe and then typed :

```
ping fgroupindonesia.com
```

it returns a true respond such as :

```
C:\Users\admin>ping fgroupindonesia.com

Pinging fgroupindonesia.com [219.83.68.83] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 219.83.68.83: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=55
Reply from 219.83.68.83: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=55
Reply from 219.83.68.83: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=55
Reply from 219.83.68.83: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=55

Ping statistics for 219.83.68.83:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 24ms, Maximum = 25ms, Average = 24ms
```

it seems okay, but whey can't be opened via Browser?
Any clue ?

[image]

When i tried to **telnet using port 80** :

```
telnet www.fgroupindonesia.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

it gave me this output :

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Thu, 21 Apr 2016 07:53:37 GMT
Server: Apache
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html



<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.or
g/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
                                         <html>
                                                 <head>
                                                           <title>400 Bad Reques
t</title>
             <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"
/>
      <style type="text/css">
                                     body {
                                                        font-family: Verdana, Ar
ial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                                        font-size: 12px;
                                                                        backgrou
nd-color:#367E8E;
                                scrollbar-base-color: #005B70;
                                                                        scrollba
r-arrow-color: #F3960B;
                                scrollbar-DarkShadow-Color: #000000;

color: #FFFFFF;
                                margin:0;
                                                 }
                                                          a { color:#021f25; tex
t-decoration:none}
                          h1 {
                                        font-size: 18px;
                                                                        color: #
FB9802;
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                                                background-image: url(sys_cpanel
/images/bottombody.jpg);
                                        background-repeat: repeat-x;

padding:5px 0 10px 15px;
                                                margin:0;
                                                                 }
                                                                          #body-
content p {
                        padding-left: 25px;
                                                        padding-right: 25px;

        line-height: 18px;
                                        padding-top: 5px;
                                                                        padding-
bottom: 5px;
                    }
                             h2 {
                                                font-size: 14px;

font-weight: bold;
                                color: #FF9900;
                                                        padding-left: 15px;

   }
        </style>
                  </head>
                           <body>
                                     <div id="body-content">
                                                              <!-- start content
-->

   <!--
         instead of REQUEST_URI, we could show absolute URL via:
                                                                 http://HTTP_HOS
T/REQUEST_URI
                 but what if its https:// or other protocol?

                                                                    SERVER_PORT_
SECURE doesn't seem to be used
                                  SERVER_PORT logic would break if they use alte
rnate ports
           -->

              <h1>400 Bad Request</h1>
                                      <p>Your browser sent a request that this s
erver could not understand:</p>
                                 <blockquote>
                                                 (none)/ (port 80)
                                                                    </blockquote
>
  <p>
         Please forward this error screen to 219.83.68.83's
                                                                <a href="mailto:
terbanku@gmail.com?subject=Error message [400] 400 Bad Request for (none)/ port
80 on Thursday, 21-Apr-2016 14:53:37 WIB">
                                              WebMaster</a>.
                                                            </p>
                                                                <hr />


                                                                      <!-- end c
ontent -->
              </div>
                      </body>
                             </html>


Connection to host lost.

C:\Users\admin>
```

Comment: Check if your server has port 80 listening. Then check to see if you can telnet to your server on port 80.  `ping` and `http` are not related. Also check your web service log files.

Comment: i used the telnet command but returned the above message... @cuongnv

Comment: `my website can get ping but status always “Waiting” when visiting via browser` - Well, PING isn't an HTTP testing tool... so there's that...

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons for the symptoms you see. However the most common reason is a PMTU discovery issue.

The simplest workaround for a PMTU discovery problem is to reduce the MTU used on either the client or the server. If there are multiple network interfaces, you only need to reduce the MTU on the network interface used to send packets between client and server.

Take note of the currently configured MTU before making any changes. Then try reducing it to 1280. If that works the problem is most likely due to a PMTU discovery problem.

If changing the MTU to 1280 does not help, you will have to inspect a packet capture of the traffic to identify the problem.

The `400 Bad Request` error you got when using `telnet` to send a request manually is due to you typing a malformed HTTP request. In HTTP/1.1 it is mandatory to include a `Host` header.

You can try this instead:

```
telnet www.fgroupindonesia.com 80
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.fgroupindonesia.com
```